# MariaDB cast binary as int

Tags: mysql, binary, mariadb

Good day! 
I have a table T1 (at MariaDB) with binary column C1. It has some bytes.

When I do select HEX I have following:

```
select HEX(SUBSTRING((select C1 from T1 where <some restrictions>), 254, 2));
+----------------------------------------------------------------------+
| HEX(SUBSTRING((select C1 from T1 where <some restrictions>), 254, 2)) |
+----------------------------------------------------------------------+
| 1200                                                                 |
+----------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

But I failed to convert the result as INT:

```
select cast((SUBSTRING((select C1 from T1 where <some restrictions>), 254, 2)) as int);
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| cast((SUBSTRING((select C1 from T1 where <some restrictions>), 254, 2)) as int) |
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|                                                                              0 |
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

So, my questions are - why does it occur and how can I cast binary as int?

Comment: `UNHEX("1200")` is not a string of digits, so it is interpreted as 0.  (The `substring` is a red herring.)

Answer (score 0):

Types are: **unsigned integer** or **signed integer**

```
select cast((substring((select C1 from T1 where <some restrictions>), 254, 2)) as unsigned integer);

select cast(substring( '12345', 1, 2 ) as unsigned integer)
```